# 'Controller' is namespace but is used like a type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

When i create new controller always throw an error "Controller'] is namespace but is used like a type".I dont know how to fix it i hve install the package.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ODS.jpg)

Comment: Change your namespace so its not the same as the name of the class - eg `namespace WebApplication1.Controllers` (plural)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the **question itself**.

Answer (score 25):

change the folder name to Controllers and namespace to Controllers, so your code should look like this

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
   public class UserController : Controller
   {
```

Comment: That worked like charm! You need to check every controller you have and change its name space from Controler to Controllers, so VS is not confused.

Answer (score 4):

you have created folder name as controller that stop inherit Controller class so please change your folder name controller to controllers.

It work for me.